# How can I say this in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to append some text after 2 closing divs to a sector element.

```
<a href="" class="thingIClicked">Click me</a>
</div>
</div>

// this is where I want to append the text
```

My code appends the text after the link. How can I say "append it after the 2nd closing div"?

```
$('a.thingIClicked').click(function() {
    $(this).append('hello');
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's probably a more elegant solution, but how about:

```
$('a.thingIClicked').click(function() {
    $(this).parent().parent().after('hello');
});
```

**Edit**: @Zack is correct (and should probably get the answer credit for this one) - my original code would have added the text *into* the second enclosing `div`, rather than *after* it. I've edited my code above accordingly.

Comment: @nrabinowitz Won't this append the text "hello" to the *inside* of the `<div>` grandparent, rather than the outside?

Comment: @Zack - yup, so true. Sorry, you were robbed on this one.

Answer (score 6):

The most direct way to do this is to find the second [parent](http://api.jquery.com/parent/) `<div>` element, and then insert the text [after](http://api.jquery.com/after/) it.

```
$('a.thingIClicked').click(function() {
    $(this).parent("div").parent("div").after("some text");
});
```

This will insert the text on the outside of the second `<div>` parent. Using [append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/) will put the text on the inside of the parent, which from your example doesn't appear to be what you want.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be to give the outer `div` an `id` and then use `$("#outerdivid")`.

EDIT: Below will not work, but leaving it here for reference
However, you should also be able to use a jquery `:parent` filter:

http://api.jquery.com/filter/

```
$('a.thingIClicked').filter(':parent').filter(':parent').click(/**/);
```

Comment: I don't think `filter()` works with `:parent` in this case unless the parent `<div>` elements are in the current jQuery object. It doesn't look like that is possible since `$(this)` is being used, meaning that the only element in the set is the `<a>` tag that was clicked.

Comment: I pulled the example from http://api.jquery.com/parent-selector/. I would expect jquery to get the parent of the jquery object(s) even if they aren't in the set originally. Haven't tried it myself though

Comment: `:parent` will match *elements having children*, but in combination with `filter()` it isn't possible to find the parent of a given element unless it is included in the jQuery object along with the given element.

Answer (score 0):

Use .insertAfter()
http://api.jquery.com/insertAfter/

```
<div class="container">
  <h2>Greetings</h2>
  <div>Hello</div>
  <div class="inner">Goodbye</div>
</div>
```

We can create content and insert it after several elements at once:

```
$('<p>Test</p>').insertAfter('.inner');
```

Answer (score -1):

Use `.insertAfter()` -  http://api.jquery.com/insertAfter/

```
<div class="container">
  <h2>Greetings</h2>
  <div>Hello</div>
  <div class="inner">Goodbye</div>
</div>
```

We can create content and insert it after several elements at once:

```
$('<p>Test</p>').insertAfter('.inner');
```